# Is there an option in the Views 3 UI to reset one section of a non-master display to the default state?

Tags: views

I've got a view that contains several different displays.  When I override an option for a single display, the header for that section is displayed in italics.  For example, if I override the **Filter Criteria** for a single display, **Filter Criteria** is shown as ***Filter Criteria*** on that display.

Is there a way to revert overridden sections (***Filter Criteria***, ***Fields***) from within the UI if I change my mind about overriding?  Of course I can manually re-create the settings to match those of the master, but this is a pain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just edit a filter or field and choose "revert to default"

[image]